# Problem with JPA query to return the latest direct messages to a user, where each message may have a parent message

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, recursive-query

I have a table called direct_message which stores a list of direct messages between users which looks like this:

| ID | PARENT_ID | RECIPIENT_ID | SENDER_ID | TITLE | MESSAGE | SENT_AT | READ_AT

---

I would like to send back a list of the most recent messages ordered by SENT_AT. I am using JPA so the query will send back the list of messages based on RECIPIENT_ID like so:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DirectMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<DirectMessage, Long> {
    Page<DirectMessage> findDirectMessageByRecipientId(Long recipientId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This is my Entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "direct_message")
public class DirectMessage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "direct_message_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "direct_message_sequence", sequenceName = "direct_message_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private DirectMessage parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "sender_id")
    private User sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "recipient_id")
    private User recipient;

    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Size(max = 4000)
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "sent_at")
    private LocalDateTime sentAt;

    private Boolean isRead = false;

    @Column(name = "read_at")
    private LocalDateTime readAt;

    @Column(name = "can_reply")
    private Boolean canReply;
}
```

However, my problem is that it will send back a message that is a parent alongside a child message which contains it as a nested parent. Here is a reduced example (with sender, recipient and other data omitted):

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "parent": null,
    "recipient": {},
    "sender": {},
    "title": "Message thread",
    "message": "Hello"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": null,
        "recipient": {},
        "sender": {},
        "title": "Message thread",
        "message": "Hello"
    },
    "recipient": {},
    "sender": {},
    "title": "Message thread",
    "message": "This is the reply"
}]
```

So as you can see, the parent message (ID 1) is duplicated (as its own row, AND also as a parent of another message which is a child of that message.
Is there a way in JPA to deduplicate this? And only send back a message if it is **not already part of another message thread**? Or if not possible in JPA is there a SQL query that would do the job?

Comment: It would help if we could see your DirectMessage entity. And I guess there is a framework doing some "magic" behind the scenes, so please include that in the tags (Spring, probably).

Comment: Are parent and child the same entity? And, can't you just exclude the parent entity in the query result?

Btw, why is the above result causing issue in your case?

Comment: @forty-two I have included the Entity class. It is using Spring Data and Postgres.
hermit - the issue as I said is that the parent is being sent as a sibling in the response, as well as a nested parent of the child row - i.e. message with ID 2 is a child and has message ID 1 nested as a parent. And message ID 1 is also present as its own row.

Comment: This has nothing (or very little) to do with JPA. How are you sending this entity - looks like JSON, but you don't have any annotations describing how you want your java model serialized into JSON. Check out Jackson, and maybe mark your parent as lazily fetched if you aren't going to be sending it with every DirectMessage request.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use entities as DTOs! Of course, there are some cases where it's acceptable, but only when you do it consciously. Let's leave it out of the scope.
More likely you will have problems with annotations, fetching, transactionality, data integrity, data validation etc.

1. an Entity object can contain more than one property, mapped to the same db field, but only one of them can be modifiable. So, depends on your needs, add another one for the `parent_id` field. Assuming you keep `parent` as it is, you can add this:

```
@Column(name = 'parent_id', insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long parentId;
```

It'll be a representation of the parent in the answer.

2. Create an appropriate DTO class with a number of properties you need to send back. Let properties names be same as in entity class (preferable but not obligatory). Don't include the `parent` property.
3. Create service (class or interface + class) which methods will transform your entities into `dto`s and vice versa. It can be simple field-by-field assignment, it can be decorator for [ModelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/user-manual/) or another useful implementation.
   The main idea is to separate transferring and storage of your data.

It's really huge subject and seems to be a one of fundamental things in data transferring and processing, and cannot be covered by the single answer here.
take a look at [The DTO Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern) and [Entity To DTO Conversion for a Spring REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) or just search here by keywords *difference between Entity and DTO*